# Is it possible to transfer Stack Overflow gmail account to another gmail account?

Tags: support, login, email

I used to connect with an old gmail account to Stack Overflow but as I created a brand new one I would like to connect with it to SO.

Comment: [This page should help you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can still log in to your old account, do that. Then go to your profile page and click "My Logins", in that popup, click "add more logins...". Then add it.

Otherwise:

Use the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form (in the footer), select "Merge Accounts".

You will need links to both user pages.

Comment: I followed the steps but when I press  "Add a login using Google" or "Add a login using Facebook" I get "Page Not Found"

Comment: Where are you doing this from? Do it from your [profile page on one of the sites](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3284623/alex-stanese). Make sure you are logged off from Google **before** you try to add it (or that you are logged in with the **new** account).

Comment: It worked! I had to change from meta to SO thanks!